# Poetry2nix flake build errors because the `poetry2nix.overrides` attribute seems to be missing

Tags: python, python-poetry, nix, nix-flake

#### Describe the issue

I'm trying to build the following flake, which apart from the overrides section is verbatim from [a templates from poetry2nix's repo](https://github.com/nix-community/poetry2nix/blob/master/templates/app/flake.nix)

```hs
{
  description =  "bear";

  inputs = {
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-23.11";
    poetry2nix = {
      url = "github:nix-community/poetry2nix";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, poetry2nix }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        inherit (poetry2nix.lib.mkPoetry2Nix { inherit pkgs; }) mkPoetryApplication;
      in
      {
        packages = {
          bear = mkPoetryApplication {
            packageName = "bearctl";
            projectDir = ./.;

            overrides = poetry2nix.overrides.withDefaults (self: super: {

              pycairo = super.pycairo.overridePythonAttrs (old: {
                nativeBuildInputs =
                  [ self.meson pkgs.buildPackages.pkg-config ];
              });
              pygobject = super.pygobject.overridePythonAttrs (old: {
                buildInputs = (old.buildInputs or [ ]) ++ [ super.setuptools ];
              });

              urllib3 = super.urllib3.overridePythonAttrs (old: {
                buildInputs = (old.buildInputs or [ ]) ++ [ self.hatch-vcs ];
              });

              pipewire-python = super.pipewire-python.overridePythonAttrs
                (old: {
                  buildInputs = (old.buildInputs or [ ]) ++ [ self.flit-core ];
                });

            });
            buildInputs =
              (with pkgs; [ pkgs.pipewire pkgs.lorri pkgs.xorg.xset pkgs.i3 ]);
          };
          default = self.packages.${system}.bear;
        };

        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          inputsFrom = [ self.packages.${system}.myapp ];
          packages = [ pkgs.poetry ];
        };
      });
}
```

which makes `nix build` balk with

```
✦ ❯ nix build .    
warning: Git tree '/home/robin/devel/bearctl' is dirty
error:
       … while evaluating the attribute 'packages.x86_64-linux.bear'

         at /nix/store/2xz05z3ar2i1fr06mzr434f6n59513g6-source/flake.nix:88:11:

           87|         packages = {
           88|           bear = mkPoetryApplication {
             |           ^
           89|             packageName = "bearctl";

       … while evaluating the attribute 'pkgs.buildPythonPackage'

         at /nix/store/yy19v2dwb8ldphvia9smajvwv3ycx2c1-source/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/passthrufun.nix:87:5:

           86|     withPackages = import ./with-packages.nix { inherit buildEnv pythonPackages;};
           87|     pkgs = pythonPackages;
             |     ^
           88|     interpreter = "${self}/bin/${executable}";

       (stack trace truncated; use '--show-trace' to show the full trace)

       error: attribute 'overrides' missing

       at /nix/store/2xz05z3ar2i1fr06mzr434f6n59513g6-source/flake.nix:92:25:

           91|
           92|             overrides = poetry2nix.overrides.withDefaults (self: super: {
             |                         ^
           93|
```

I must be doing something very obvious incredibly wrong, but i can't seem to get this to work. What is happening?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new `poetry2nix` API you need to build `poetry2nix` (and not only `mkPoetryApplication`) from `pkgs` to access the overrides. This means that you should replace

```hs
inherit (poetry2nix.lib.mkPoetry2Nix { inherit pkgs; }) mkPoetryApplication;
```

with

```hs
poetry2nix = inputs.poetry2nix.lib.mkPoetry2Nix { inherit pkgs;};
```

Below are the modifications made to your flake.nix to make it work:

```hs
{
  description =  "bear";

  inputs = {
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-23.11";
    poetry2nix = {
      url = "github:nix-community/poetry2nix";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
  };

  outputs = inputs @ { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, ...}:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        poetry2nix = inputs.poetry2nix.lib.mkPoetry2Nix { inherit pkgs; };
      in
      {
        packages = {
          bear = poetry2nix.mkPoetryApplication {
            packageName = "bearctl";
            projectDir = ./.;

            overrides = poetry2nix.overrides.withDefaults (self: super: {

              pycairo = super.pycairo.overridePythonAttrs (old: {
                nativeBuildInputs =
                  [ self.meson pkgs.buildPackages.pkg-config ];
              });
              pygobject = super.pygobject.overridePythonAttrs (old: {
                buildInputs = (old.buildInputs or [ ]) ++ [ super.setuptools ];
              });

              urllib3 = super.urllib3.overridePythonAttrs (old: {
                buildInputs = (old.buildInputs or [ ]) ++ [ self.hatch-vcs ];
              });

              pipewire-python = super.pipewire-python.overridePythonAttrs
                (old: {
                  buildInputs = (old.buildInputs or [ ]) ++ [ self.flit-core ];
                });

            });
            buildInputs =
              (with pkgs; [ pkgs.pipewire pkgs.lorri pkgs.xorg.xset pkgs.i3 ]);
          };
          default = self.packages.${system}.bear;
        };

        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          inputsFrom = [ self.packages.${system}.myapp ];
          packages = [ pkgs.poetry ];
        };
      });
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it! Thanks! Nix stuff is so confusing ;_;